# Autofac how to use Scoped dependencies in Singletons

Tags: c#, autofac

Resolving the SingletonClass gives me a new instance of LifetimeClass. Is there a way to resolve a scope dependency from Singleton within the same scope? This is a simple example I created to reproduce the unexpected behavior at my asp net core project.

```
public class LifetimeClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
public class Middle
{
    public Middle(LifetimeClass myLifetimeClass)
    {
        myLifetimeClass.Value = "OK";
    }
}

public class SingletonClass
{
    public SingletonClass(LifetimeClass myLifetimeClass)
    {

    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<LifetimeClass>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Middle>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<SingletonClass>().SingleInstance();
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var a = scope.Resolve<Middle>();
            var b = scope.Resolve<SingletonClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't inject scoped service into singleton using constructor. You can inject [`ILifetimeScope`](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/BA5D3489.htm) to your singleton and resolve the scoped service on demand. You can also encapsulate `ILifetimeScope` in `Factory<T>` to avoid service locator pattern.

Comment: This is a [captive dependencies](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this is a no. You can't expect the Lifetime class to be the same instance in both the singleton and middle. I don't believe the behaviour you're getting is unexpected.

You have the LifetimeClass registered as instance per lifetime scope. You have created a scope using BeginLifetimeScope and resolved the Middle instance through it resulting in it having it's instance of LifetimeClass being that of the containing scope.

However, the SingletonClass is registered as a singleton, so it is instantiated from the container directly as would be expected because singletons are not scoped. Therefore its instance of LifetimeClass is also instantiated in the singleton's scope, which is the container, not your scope.

So it would be expected that each of these classes will be resolved with different instances of LifetimeClass.

If you need to deal with a specific LifetimeClass in both, you will either need to change your 'singleton' class to be registered per lifetime scope, or have whatever methods act on the LifetimeClass in the singleton accept the instance as a parameter.

Comment: This is correct. [There's some good doc on lifetime in Autofac here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) that might help, but basically - if it's a singleton, it gets resolved from the root container (so it can be shared in the app) _and all of its dependencies will also be from the root container_ because those _also_ will need to be shared along with the singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Captive dependency (your `LifetimeClass`) depend upon the lifetime of its parent, therefor it will create again a new instance of `LifetimeClass`, so I can suggest not to inject it to `Middle` by the constructor but by method injection:

```
public class SingletonClass
{
    public LifetimeClass LifetimeClass { get; set; }
    public SingletonClass(LifetimeClass lifetimeClass)
    {
        this.LifetimeClass = lifetimeClass;
    }
}

public class Middle
{
    private LifetimeClass _lifetimeClass;
    public void SetLifetimeClass(LifetimeClass lifetimeClass)
    {
        this._lifetimeClass = lifetimeClass;
    }
}


containerBuilder.Register(c =>
{
    var middle = new Middle();
    middle.SetLifetimeClass(c.Resolve<SingletonClass>().LifetimeClass);
    return middle;
});
```

The scope stays intact:

```
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var a = scope.Resolve<Middle>();
    var b = scope.Resolve<SingletonClass>();
}
```

Comment: In the given example, this would be no different to registering the LifetimeClass as a singleton and leaving it in the constructor.